# Detect press of back button

Tags: android

I want to detect pressing of a back button **in service**. I've just tried this code but it didn't show me any log. Can somebody explain me why? And what should I do to make it work?

The whole idea of doing this was was taken from this tutorial http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-detect-global-touch-event.html

```
public class MyService extends Service implements View.OnKeyListener{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LinearLayout touchLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        // set layout width 30 px and height is equal to full screen
        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(30, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        touchLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        touchLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        touchLayout.setOnKeyListener(this);
        WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        // set layout parameter of window manager
        WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                30, // width of layout 30 px
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // height is equal to full screen
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, // Type Phone, These are non-application windows providing user interaction with the phone (in particular incoming calls).
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, // this window won't ever get key input focus
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        mParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;

        mWindowManager.addView(touchLayout, mParams);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            Log.v("Point","KeyCode_Back");
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service is not a View, implementing a View.OnKeyListener does not deliver your desired functionality.

A Service is intended to be an "Activity without UI" which runs in the background of your application. You can use Binders/Broadcasts to communicate with your service but UI interaction is best left to Activity/Fragments.

Annex:
I guess you are trying to build a overlay like in the link you posted in the comment. This Tutorial is from 2013 so things have changed.

In general the Android system discourages App beheaviour like the below described method. Coding like this, goes into the category Lockscreen/Kiosk-App behaviour which is considered as malware.

If you want to accomplish a little side menu inside your app you can do this perfectly fine without using such a service. Outside your App you still have the options of using widgets, which are more user friendly than hardcoding something on the screen.

Comment: @r%c3%bcdiger I've tried to do something like this http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-detect-global-touch-event.html